# Changing the position of UIImageView - why am I getting a "request for member error"

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimageview

> Request for member 'bunny' in something not a structure or union

Why exactly am I getting this error? My line looks like this:

```
[self.bunny setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)];
```

With a declared property as:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *bunny;
```

And I init it with:

```
self.bunny = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 50, 50)];
self.bunny.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bunny.png"];
```

But all the assignment lines error with that error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with the code you have posted.  Make sure that you haven't inadvertently declare that property as a `UIImage` instead of a `UIImageView`.  If you haven't done that, please post all the code from the VC.

For other's info, in Xcode 4.4 & up, the properties are auto-synthesized to `property = _property`.

Ok.  From the project you sent me, there were two issues:

1. You need to declare that property with retain directive instead of strong if you aren't using `ARC` (which the project you sent me isn't)
2. You have instantiated that class as a category, you cannot do that and have a private class variable.  Either remove that category name, or declare

`@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *bunny;`

in the header file instead.

And the implementation file:

```
#import "SlidingTableViewCell.h"
#import "CellBack.h"
#import "CellFront.h"


@interface SlidingTableViewCell (ShitBalst)
-(void)springBack;
-(void)toggleTableScrolling:(BOOL)canScroll;
@end


@implementation SlidingTableViewCell
@synthesize bunny;

#define kDragDist 80.0
```

BTW - here is the project that I updated:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3660978/TableViewCellSlider.zip

Comment: Updated answer and included link to fixed project

Answer (score 0):

Have you synthesized bunny?

`@synthesize bunny = _bunny;`

Comment: I'm in iOS 6, I've never synthesized a variable in this project.

Answer (score 0):

The object `self` does not have a 'bunny'.  Typically this is because you haven't synthesized the property.  But you would see a compiler warning for that.  Did you overlook the warning?

Comment: I'm in iOS 6, I've never synthesized a variable in this project

Comment: Confirm that a) there are no compiler warnings about 'bunny' accessors and b) self.bunny is actually assigned with its UIImageView.